# grabbing Html of $(this) in Jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I grab the Html for `$(this)` in a following function

```
allhdn.each(function (){
      var $this = $(this);       
      var newHtml = (str + $this.html());
});
```

`$(this).html()` returns empty string.

Comment: what elements are you iterating over?

Comment: That looks correct.  Perhaps the element actually has no content?

Comment: What is in `allhdn` object? Which types of controls?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder. `$this = $(this)`

Comment: allHdn is all the Hidden<td>5<input type=hidden value="5" name='hdnFields' id='hdnFields'></td>n fields. I have tds in this format.    allHdn is  var allhdnMonths = $('input[Id^="hdnFields"]');

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, what do you really want? Tell us in plain english!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).html()` gets the *inner* html code for the tag. Because the tags you're iterating over are input fields, they don't have any inner tags. To fix this, I think you need to wrap in a new tag and take the inner html of *that* tag:

```
// wrap in an enclosing tag
$this.wrap('<span/>');
// get the code
var newHtml = (str + $this.parent().html());
```

But as @Interstellar_Coder noted, are you sure you want the HTML, and not just the `.val()` on the hidden inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a variable scope issue.

```
var html;
var newHtml;
allhdn.each(function (){
    html = $(this).html();  
    newHtml = (str + html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `input` you want `.val()`

```
var newVal = (str + $this.val());
```

Comment: val() will not return me the html.

Comment: Input's don't have any html :-P